# Matching coordinates on Google Maps to planetary.js

Tags: google-maps, planetary.js

I am looking to migrate from Google Maps to planetary.js and I need to move a bunch of markers.  Does anyone know how Google Maps coordinates match to coordinates in planetary.js?

If I have a Google Maps location such as "-33.654437, 151.188164" - what does this map to in planetary.js?

Answer (score 0):

Those should be latitude/longitude coordinates, and you can be converted into `x/y` coordinates on the planet's projection via D3's [projection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#_projection). The projection is exposed in Planetary.js as `planet.projection`.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems they are the same, switching the x and y coordinate works for me.

Google / Openstreetmap: `"-33.654437, 151.188164"`
Planetary.js: `(151.188164, -33.654437)`